# Is there any way I can pull a json file with node here instead of react.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I want to add items to a shopping cart using a json file and node.js. I have found this tutorial that uses react.js but I want to know can node.js be used instead and how it can be applied?

https://github.com/scotch-io/react-flux-cart

Comment: You ask if Node.js can create/process JSON files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`express` module will be who handle the request from the client. `express` helps you to recieve and send json files to browser.

For saving the cart in the server, you have to use a database or file storage. like `mongodb` or `mysql` or simply using `fs.writeFile`

After you install node, and express (`npm i express`) this is a code example for send to the user a JSON of his cart:

```
app.get('/cart',function(req,res){
   res.send({total:250, items: [{name:'mybook',price:250}])
})
```

Good luck learning NodeJS.

Comment: Thanks amina... Do you have any demos or examples of how node.js would pull json as a file and display these products in a shopping cart?

Comment: Or even php pulling json

Comment: the json file.. I want to put the json products into a shopping cart